# USB CDC device working on Windows but not working on Ubuntu. Can I fix situation?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, serial-port

I have USB CDC device. It working on Windows. I test it using putty.
But it don't work on Ubuntu. I use ubuntu 10.04 with kernel 2.6.32-122-rtai. When I plug  device in message appears in dmesg:

```
[40194.004034] usb 3-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 12
[40194.173219] usb 3-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

But it hasn't message about serial port file (like /dev/ttyUSB1).

Does exists some program or command to make this device visible on my Ubuntu conputer as serial port?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this using Symbol barcode readers put into CDC mode.  What I found happened was that they showed up in /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyACM1, not /dev/ttyUSB.

Ubuntu 10.04 is new enough to use udev so the /dev/ttyACM* devices won't show up until the device is plugged in.  Try:

```
cd /dev
ls -l ttyACM*
```

If you see nothing when the device is unplugged and something when it's plugged in, you've found your device.

I found that the Symbol device didn't tell me where it was accessible.  I had to find that out by poking around like I've detailed above.

Another command that might be helpful for you is:

```
lsusb
```